# Determine programmatically whether an expression is always defined

Tags: functions, computational-mathematics, programming

I would like to determine programmatically whether a given expression is always defined, or if it could have an undefined result.

For instance, take the following computation:

```
a = rand() * 1000  // a real number >=0 and <1000
b = trunc( a )*2   // an even number between 0 and 1998
c = sin( a )       // a real number >=-1 and <=1
d = pow( c, b )    // a positive real number >=0 and <=1
e = log( a )       // either undefined (-Infinity), or a real number <6.907…
f = sqrt( e )      // either undefined, or a real number >=0 and <2.628…
```

How can I write a program that tells me that e and f can be undefined, while the others are always defined? Is this even possible?

I asked on StackOverflow ([Detect whether an expression could have an undefined result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583503/detect-whether-an-expression-could-have-an-undefined-result)) and would love to find an existing library. Some commenters suggested to post here.

I've tried to approach this using interval arithmetic. That works with a lot of continuous functions, but doesn't work with others. For instance `pow(-1, x)` requires to know whether `x` is 0 or a positive even number.

Would you know other ways to approach this problem?

Comment: As a consequence of Rice theorem I doubt there can exist a general technique. If you have a limited set of (mathematical) operations you could define a domain and a range for every operation and check that (in the case of nested operations you want that the range of every operator is contained in the domain of the next).

Comment: What if your program contained a loop that ran a procedure for which it is unknown what the result is? There are many such procedures (for instance a loop to check the Collatz conjecture). So in general this is not possible. If you are only using functions which you know to tell for sure what their result is then it is not a difficult task and the way to implement it would depend on the programming language and the question would have to be asked on stackoverflow, this is just a sort of a fancy type checking. Again, in general there is no way to make this automatic.

Comment: @Snaw for my goal it would be enough to support a small set of standard functions... like common arithmetic and trigonometric ones. It would be fine if recursive functions aren't supported. In any case, yeah, it seems like it's not really feasible.

Comment: @BlueNebula Collatz only needs arithmetic and a single loop, so as long as you allow those, the result will be unknown. If you mean that you are not allowing loops then it is probably possible.

Comment: @Snaw: correct, I wouldn't allow loops. Only "stateless" functions with no recursion.
Anyways I think that it's really really difficult no matter what. I just realized that even wolfram alpha is not able to tell that `pow( abs(x)+1, x ) >= 0` is an alternative form for `true`.

Comment: @BlueNebula That's likely because wolfram alpha is assuming the variable $x$ to be a complex number unless you tell it otherwise. For complex numbers this is not necessarily correct, for instance for $x=i$ you would get a complex result which we cannot say is greater than zero. Maybe if you can find a way to tell wolfram alpha that you are assuming $x$ is real then the expression will evaluate to true. I don't know how to do this in wolfram alpha but in other math software there are ways to specify this.